# How to set facebook fan page height

Tags: html

I created an html page for facebook it's height is 650px and turned off Auto Scroll but it shows vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Fascinating! Any other interesting facts your would like to share with us? Or do you have a question relating to this?

Comment: He wants to get rid of scrollbars I think. ETA: LMFAO!!! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Just because the content fits within the standard canvas height doesn't necessarily mean that the scrollbars won't appear.  The scrollbar will also appear if the width overflows the canvas (520px).

The following doesn't apply in your case but based on your title others may find it useful.  The fan page canvas height can be changed by using the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) -- specifically FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow or FB.Canvas.setSize.

Answer (score 0):

Add a selector too the fan page div.

```
<div id="myfanpage">
</div>
```

then add this css to your stylesheet:

```
#myfanpage{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:650px;
}
```

That will completely disable scrollbars and make your div exactly 650px in height!

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little more what you're trying to do, maybe I don't understand.